# gitignore file ignore cachebusted files

Tags: git, gitignore

I have my `.gitignore` working fine but for some reason I cannot get it to ignore my `/min` folder which contains, among other things, my cache busted js in the format of `whatever.min.v0.0.1.js`

Here is my current `.gitignore` file:

```
node_modules/
.sass-cache/
public/stylesheets/*.css
public/min/*.js
```

How do I get it to ignore just everything in the `public/min` folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your ignore rule looks correct as long as that is the correct folder structure so my guess is that you are trying to ignore files which you were previously tracking changes on?

Try running the following:

`git rm --cached public/min/*`

That should clear any tracked files within the min folder and from now on your `.gitignore` rule should work correctly.

Comment: Yup... that's what it was... Thank you. :)